# Don't understand usage of booleans in infamous bubble sort

Tags: sorting, boolean, bubble-sort

I wasn't left with any opportunity but to register here to seek for clarification of one problem that I'm struggling to comprehend. 
I'm a dummy with close to zero coding experience and am learning AppleScript and in a textbook I'm reading (H.Rosenthal, H.Sanderson. Comprehensive guide to Scripting and Automation on Mac OSX.2010, 3rd edition) I stumbled upon a brief outline of Bubble sort. The example in question is:

```
    on bubblesort(the_list)
    set is_sorted to false
    repeat until is_sorted
    set is_sorted to true
    repeat with i from 1 to (count the_list)
    if item i of the_list > item (i + 1) of the_list then
    set {item i of the_list, item (i + 1) of the_list} to {item (i + 1) of        the_list, item i of the_list}
    set is_sorted to false
    end if
    end repeat
    end repeat
    end bubblesort
```

I understand the essentials of bubble sort, I know how looping works as well as when one ought to use "repeat" statements. What I can't fathom is the usage of booleans and I failed to find an explanation of any kind regarding just the matter of using booleans in this algorithm and how the two loops interact with one another. Here's my logic, please correct me where I'm missing:

1. Since the type of sorting we're going to apply to the given list is a cycle process we'll utilize repeat loops of two kinds: "repeat with… from… to…" to loop over every item of the_list and "repeat until" to perform as many passes as the process will need.
2. "Repeat until" will be an outer loop while "repeat with… from… to…" will be nested inside the former.
3. The boolean expression for outer loop will be a value of newly created variable is_sorted which, as its class implies, will store a varied value. Since any variable must be defined we set it to "false" outside the loop.
4. The conditional statement "if" of the inner loop presumes "true" when `item i of the_list > item (i + 1)`. If this condition is met then is_sorted gets "false" (just as it's set). Eventually when all items in the list (the_list) are sorted this condition will change to "true" and so will be a value of is_sorted. Am I right? And so here the problem emerges:
5. List item

   - What's the exact order of actions?
   - Are the actions inside the inner loop are executed in the first place or all the actions within the both loops from top to bottom are?
   - When is_sorted acquires "false" value where did the output of this variable is directed afterwards?
   - When the inner loop's `is_sorted` variable is "false" does the action "bounce" to repeat until `is_sorted` that is set to "false"?
   - How does is_sorted within the inner loop talk to `is_sorted` of the outer loop? Why immediately change the value of `is_sorted` to "true" right after declaring it as "false"?
   - How exactly and when does the `is_sorted` that set to true before the inner loop respond to the result of the inner loop?

It was difficult to formulate these questions, so if I'm given response I would be grateful. I'm sure I have skipped some questions that I simply forgot, but thankfully, will recover later.

[Visualisation of my understanding of bubble sort](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ncF4E.jpg)

Comment: Please reduce your question to something shorter and understandable

Comment: I'm new to this discussion board, so I'm trying to get into the whole formatting thing which is quite intricate here.

Answer (score 0):

> usage of booleans in infamous bubble sort

It should just be one boolean, `is_sorted`. It is used as an early exit optimization for bubble sort. The outer loop sets `is_sorted` to true, and if the code in the inner loop detects elements out of order, it sets `is_sorted` to false in addition to swapping the elements. It might be easier to understand this if the psuedo code is indented:

```
bubblesort(the_list)
    set is_sorted to false
    repeat until is_sorted
        set is_sorted to true
        repeat with i from 1 to (count the_list)
            if item i of the_list > item (i + 1) of the_list then
                set {item i of the_list, item (i + 1) of the_list} to
                    {item (i + 1) of the_list, item i of the_list}
                set is_sorted to false
            end if
        end repeat
    end repeat
end bubblesort
```

An alternative name and sense of the boolean would be an indicator if any swaps occurred, and if no swaps occurred, then the elements would be sorted. In this case swaps would initially be set to true, then set to false in the outer loop and set to true in the inner loop if any out of order elements were detected and swapped.

Comment: your edited out piece "An alternative name and sense of the boolean would be an indicator if any swaps occurred, and if no swaps occurred, then the elements would be sorted. In this case swaps would be set to false in the outer loop and set to true in the inner loop if any out of order elements were detected and swapped." was actually good to go because of its explanative nature. It's I just can't understand whether "repeat until is_sorted" mean "repeat until false" or "repeat until true"? When does is_sorted of the outer loop has "true" and when does it have "false"?

Comment: @scrutinizer1 - Thanks for catching that. I have it back and updated to explain the initial setting (true, then set to false in outer loop). "Repeat until is_sorted" means repeat until `is_sorted` is true. So the initial setting is false, the outer loop sets it to true, and the inner loop sets it to false if out of order elements are detected (which would also mean a swap occurred). For a "swaps  occurred" boolean, the true / false would be reversed, and the outer loop would be "repeat until no swaps occurred" .

Comment: I edited my original post to add a pic of how do I imagine bubble sort's inner workings. I see that it swaps false with true immediately after execution of the outer loop's statements begin. If the inner loop swaps two items then the outer loop's is_sorted is set to "false" once again only to be changed to "true" in the next expression. Am I correct?
And if the two consecutive items are sorted, i.e. the conditional statement isn't true then... what happens? It skips the loop? However, if it does, then how do it manages to proceed to the end of the list looping over the rest of items?

Comment: @scrutinizer1 - What the bubble sort does is compare adjacent elements to see if they are out of order and if so, swaps them. On the first inner loop, this will move the "largest" element to the end of the list (if it's not already there). On the second inner loop, it will move the "next to largest" element to the next to last position in the array and so on, except that this example code always compares to the end of the array, not keeping track of which ones already in place. In the inner loop, if there are no out of order elements (no swaps), the sorting is done and the outer loop exits.

Comment: You're speaking of general conception which I fully understand, on a general level. However what causes me trouble is not this but the mechanism on a low level of executing boolean statements. I constantly fail to grasp why each of the booleans is where it is. That's why I'm trying to build a scheme for my own convenience:
1. Why is_sorted is given "false" before the outer loop? Possible answer: just to have this variable defined in order to avoid a script error, as a variable needs value. Correct or incorrect?
2. Immediately on beginning of execution is_sorted by design acquires "true" -->

Comment: --> so "repeat until is_sorted" is actually "repeat until true" which means that when repeat until gets "true" the whole process ends, terminates, aborts etc. Correct or incorrect?
3. Now on to the inner loop: let's say the loop encounters a first pair out of order. In terms of booleans it means that after the two being swapped for each other is_sorted is set automatically to "false". To elaborate deeper the fact means that for a brief time "repeat until is_sorted" is actually "repeat until false"  which gets changed to "repeat until true" immediately. Correct or incorrect? -->

Comment: --> If correct then what the purpose of assigning is_sorted to "false" only to have it changed to "true" in the next step? What a part of process this corresponds to?
4. Let's say the inner loop encounters a pair that is in order. Obviuosly is_sorted is NOT going to acquire "false". It means that it is being set automatically to "true". Correct or incorrect? If correct then repeat "until is_sorted" is actually "repeat until true" and the whole sorting must (should?) stop, abort, terminate. Correct or incorrect? The point 4. is the most troublesome for me.  If is_sorted gets "true" then -->

Comment: --> how does the sorting proceeds through the rest of the items both sorted and unsorted? What is my missing? What am I overlooking?

Comment: @scrutinizer1 - the inner loop could benefit by using a variable initially set to (count the list), which is decremented after each inner loop to avoid proceeding past the unsorted elements into the already sorted elements.